# Он пожалел, что его жена не приняла участие в конкурсе: наверняка она победилa бы

Tags: синтаксис

*Он пожалел, что его жена не приняла участие в конкурсе: **наверняка она победилa бы.***

Выделенное предложение - это простое предложение? (меня как-то двоеточие сбивает с толку)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В школьной практике допускается сказать,что сложное предложение состоит из простых предложений, в то же время существует строгое определение: сложное предложение - это соединение предикативных единиц (основ), связанных грамматически, семантически и интонационно.

В приведенном примере три предикативные основы, две первые основы входят в состав СПП, между СПП и третьей основой бессоюзная связь. Эту третью основу только условно можно назвать простым предложением.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя говорить о том, простое ли это предложение, если выделенная часть входит в состав сложного синтаксического целого. Если бы оно было изъято, то тогда можно с уверенностью заявлять, что оно простое, так как в нём одна грамматическая основа: ***она победила бы***. Двоеточие вас не должно смущать. В приведенном вами предложении наблюдаются две связи: СПП (сложносочиненная) и БСП (бессоюзная).

Comment: Спасибо, я поправил.